# Losing cookies in headers when sending HTTP request to other domain

Tags: http, cookies, cross-domain

I have a client hosted on one domain `app.example.com` and a API server on other subdomain `api.example.com`. In development mode there are `localhost:3000` and `localhost:4000`.

I am trying to send HTTP requests that include `Cookie` header. This worked just fine while everything was on the same server and domain. Then I changed code and added CORS also included `withCredentials` property on `Axios` HTTP library. In development mode it works, cookies are sent in requests, however in production this breaks. All requests seem to work fine, both `OPTIONS` and followed `POST` requests get `200`ish response.

This is my CORS setup on the API server:

```
server.all('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', DEV ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'https://example.com')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    next()
  })
```

and this is how my `axios` requests look like:

```
axios(`${API_URL}/someEndpoint`, {
    method: 'post',
    withCredentials: true,
    data,
  })
```

However my requests do not include Cookie headers:

[image]

Then I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies) and answers say its impossible to share cookies among domains. Now I am extremely confused.

I use cookies in my headers to detect which user sends which request. If I lose cookies in headers I can no longer track which request was sent by which (not logged in) user and therefore I can't aggregate this data for statistics anymore.

My application was monolith but I had to separate API server from render server. Is it possible to still read cookies in headers even tho servers use different domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that sharing cookies this way among different domains is rather impossible ~ security risk, however in question it was also mentioned sharing among subdomains and that is possible by adding `domain` property while setting cookie.

```
cookies.set('cookieName', 'cookieValue' , { path: '/', domain: DEV ? undefined : '.example.com' })
```

Note that value starts with `.`

Meanwhile, workaround for sending cookie values among different domains would be sending custom headers with cookie values.